# How to put set of links in Link List card in Fiori Overview page?

Tags: sapui5

I want to put external links such as(google.com, yahoo.com) in my Link List card. if anybody knows how to do it that would be a great help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use sap.m.Link. I did simple demo for [you](http://jsbin.com/kotoheyeji/1/edit?html,js,output).

```
var oLink = new sap.m.Link();
oLink.setText("Link to URL (Target: www.sap.com)");
oLink.setTooltip("Target: www.sap.com");
oLink.setHref("http://www.sap.com");
oLink.setTarget("www.sap.com");     
oLink.placeAt("content");
```

Comment: Here is the [link to the documentation for the Link List Card](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/0326f910c6af4fb1b86f2810ee10419e.html).

Comment: Hey @Jaro  thanks for the reply, but I want to put links in Link List Card which means I will have to configure my annotation.xml file so i can show links in card and i don't know how to do it. i think your solution is not for the Link List card(Fiori overview page) 
Thanks

Comment: Ok I see, you are welcome Ashok, but I did not help you. I will leave my answer in order to see link to the documentation, which is in the comment.